# hi.i need to create a spring mvc project with Intellij IDEA to do w crud to a MYSQL db

Tags: spring-mvc

i need to create a spring mvc project with Intellij IDEA to do w crud to a MYSQL db.Can some one help me with z source code running in Intellij IDEA???

Answer (score 0):

Here You have Spring MVC example and PostgreSQL database. Only thing you have to do is to change configuration form PostgresSQL to MySQL:

https://github.com/DanielMichalski/altkom-spring-mvc